# DSP stackexchange question suggested to be posted here, about LaTeX and math equations

Tags: learning

My biggest stumbling block has been to write math equations neatly, as I write on paper. Many advise me to use LaTeX that I have to learn. I also used to not know how to write here. Now I am learning how to write better when someone edits my questions or answers, and I also get an idea about learning. If I see an equation of interest, I go into edit mode and see what the code for the format actually is. That is one of way learning. Where can I start systematic learning, I mean the references and links etc? And another question is, does that help me in learning/using LaTeX?

Comment: You could start with the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)...

Comment: This looks like a clear dupe to me: if I'm wrong, comment and I'll reopen.

Comment: taking into account the text of the question, namely that you learn from how questions are edited, i have taken the liberty of editing your question.  the pointer to the earlier question is a good one, and i wish you success in learning both (La)TeX and how to cope in the stackexchange environment.  welcome to tex.sx.